# If statement for multiple scenarios

Tags: c#

I am struggling completing this if statement. There must be an easier way to go through all combination because this can't be good practice.

```
if( one == true && two == true && three == true ...)
else if( one != true && two == true && three == true ...)
```

I wonder if I want to go through all combinations is there any other way of doing this rather than duplicating the expression?

Comment: There is a way to get through all of these, best way may be if you declare one,two and three as type booleans..

Comment: you can remove all the `== true`, if the types are `bool`

Comment: @Jonesy, while that will make the code shorter, it's the same thing.

Comment: It might be helpful to show your concrete situation so we're not guessing at what may or may not be applicable.

Comment: @gunr2171 hence the comment rather than answer.  It seemed worth noting at least.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way would be converting your `one`, `two`, and `three` values to a single `int` with the bits properly set, and using a `switch` statement on binary masks, like this:

```
int combined=0;
// Construct a binary representation using your Boolean values as bits:
// Value of one goes to bit zero
if (one) combined   |= (1 << 0);
// Value of one goes to bit one
if (two) combined   |= (1 << 1);
// Value of three goes to bit two
if (three) combined |= (1 << 2);
switch (combined) {
case 0: // All false
    break;
case 1: // one is true, other are all false
    break;
...
case 7: // All true
    break;
}
```

All eight combinations are now encoded as integer values:

```
int    three two one
_--    ----- --- ---
0    -    0   0   0 
1    -    0   0   1 
2    -    0   1   0 
3    -    0   1   1 
4    -    1   0   0 
5    -    1   0   1 
6    -    1   1   0 
7    -    1   1   1
```

It goes without saying that you need to heavily comment code like this for readers of your code who have not memorized binary representations of small numbers.

Comment: this seems great. can you please explain the procedure on this if you don't mind? thanks

Comment: @Passionforprogrammingc simply: binary arithmetic

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far

Comment: @Passionforprogrammingc The core of Marc's answer is identical to this one - construct a binary representation, and jump based on the combination. The only difference is in the construction of the `combined` flags: I used a sequence of `if`s, while Marc preferred ternary expressions.

Comment: You could make an array of 7 functions and index into the array to really be fast.

Comment: Great answers! I knew there should be a way. I never though of arithmetic binary it is the simplest because even if the value of the expression increases you can still calculate the combination required.

Comment: Something that might make this more legible going forward would be to use an enum with the `[Flags]` attribute - instead of three separate bools?

Answer (score 18):

You *could* do something like:

```
int i = (one ? 1 : 0) | (two ? 2 : 0) | (three ? 4 : 0);

switch(i)
{
     case 0:
         // ...
     case 1:
         // ...
     case 7:
         // ...
}
```

This will be very fast - it'll be a direct jump ([the `switch` opcode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.switch(v=vs.110).aspx)), and the expressions will only be evaluated once each.

Comment: I wish MS would do something like  `(one ? 0b1 : 0) | (two ? 0b10 : 0) | (three ? 0b100 : 0);`....binary representation ( I know it's the same thing but still...)

Comment: You could make an array of 7 functions and index into the array to really be fast.

Comment: @RoyiNamir that has been on the radar for Roslyn / C# 6 for ages; not sure it is enabled at the moment, though

Comment: @MarcGravell - I guessed you've tested it to say with such certainty -- in C or C++ it wouldn't be, but strange stuff happens in C#

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `one != true` on the second line, since you've already eliminated the case where all are true. You can simplify using that:

```
if (one && two && three) {
}
else if (one && two) { 
} 
else if (two && three) {
}
else if (one && three) {
}
else if (one) {
}
else if (two) {
}
else if (three) {
}
else
{
  // none true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try this:

```
if (one && two && three)
{
    // Do something
}
else if(one && two && three ...)
{
    // Do Something else
}
```

to check a false statement use '!':

```
if (!one && two ...)
```

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this is to have each of those items declared as a bool. That way, you can eliminate all of the `== ?` lines, and have something like this:

```
bool one = true; // Random decision to call it true, just for testing
bool two = false;
bool three = true;

if(one && two && three)
    // Do something
else if(!one && two && three)
    // Do something else.
```