# c# - Method call based on Bool without if statements

Tags: c#, methods, boolean-logic

It was difficult to formulate a title. 
However, I'll quickly explain my current options and hopefully someone can tell me a neater way to make this work.

---

The first "quick" solution we had was:

```
public class Test
{
        public bool UseSomething = false;
        public bool UseSomethingElse = false;
        public bool UseAnother = false;

    public void MyMethod(){

        if(UseSomething){
            if(UseSomethingElse){
                if(UseAnother){
                    // UseSomething, UseSomethingElse, UseAnother
                }
                else{
                    // UseSomething, UseSomethingElse
                }
            }
            else{
                // UseSomething
            }
        }
        else if(UseSomethingElse){
            if(UseAnother){
                // UseSomethingElse, UseAnother
            }
            else{
                // UseSomethingElse
            }
        }

        // etc...

    }
}
```

---

Now this was an ugly solution in my opinion and became cluttered really quickly, especially if you wanted to add options. And not to mention, anyone other than myself would be lost at first sight as to where to go/change/whatever.

So I quickly came up with another solution as following:

```
public class Test
{
    public bool UseSomething = false;
    public bool UseSomethingElse = false;
    public bool UseAnother = false;
    short options = 0;

    public void Init() // call this @ start of your program
    {
        if (UseSomething)
            options += 1;
        if (UseSomethingElse)
            options += 2;
        if (UseAnother)
            options += 4;
    }

    public void MyMethod(){ 
        Something something = MatchOption(foo); 
    }
    public void MatchOption(Foo foo)
    {
        switch (options) // based on the Options value (which is unique for every bool-triggered) perform a specific method.
        {
            case 0: //000
                return NoOptions(foo);
            case 1: //100
                return OptionSomething(foo);
            case 2: //010
                return OptionSomethingElse(foo);
            case 4: //001
                return ... etc;
            case 3: //110
                break; 
            case 5: //101
                break;
            case 6: //011
                break;
            case 7: // 111
                break;
            case -1:
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Now, this makes it more manageable and people basically wouldn't have to worry about which if/else statement to put stuff in. Also the methods are clean and only do what they are supposed to do.

But still I can't let it go that there MUST be some other way to do this.

This isn't much a question where the code wouldn't work. It's more that I want a "best" or "most clean" way to do this. ^_^
I'm third year Software Engineer student and still looking for ways to clean or optimize my code.

If you have comments or suggestions please let me know!

**Note: this is pseudo code mostly, I haven't run or tested this. It wasn't about working, it's a concept I'm trying to figure out.**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's about code-review, therefore it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Related: [If statement for multiple scenarios](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26347287/335858).

Comment: Do all DoSomething functions have the same signature?

Comment: For your switch-case statement, you could use an enum to make it more readable: `case Options.UseSomething | Options.UseSomethingElse:` is more descriptive than `case 3:`.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet But I can't use the enum in this current context can I? It has to do the `init()` method first, based on that value it would have to set the enum? How would one go about that?

Comment: `options` should be an `Options` (your enum) instead of a `short`. In Init, `options += 1` becomes `options |= Options.UseSomething`. You may also want to read about the `Flags` attribute for enums like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (see the Remarks section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go and for a more object way of doing this.

First there is the DoSomething hierarchy.

```
abstract class BaseDoingThings
{
    abstract void Do();
}

class Something : BaseDoingThings
{
    override Do() { ... }
}

class SomethingElse : BaseDoingThings
{
    override Do() { ... }
}
```

Then there is the test class

```
class Test
{
    private List<BaseDoingThings> stuffToDo = new List<BaseDoingThings>();
    public void AddStuffToDo(BaseDoingThings todo)
    {
        stuffToDo.Add(todo);
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        foreach(var stuff in stuffToDo)
        {
            stuff.Do();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the basic idea. Now you have to adapte to your case which mean that you have to correctly define the `BaseDoingThings` interface.

Comment: This is interesting. Definitely seems to work for specific causes.
It would technically be the same code-length though right? Because where in my Switch Case I'm writing 8 methods, you would write 8 classes extending the `BaseDoingThings`.

Comment: Choosing this as most correct answer as it would allow me to perform SPECIFIC actions based on all 8 options. Thanks! ^_^ It wasn't exactly what I was looking for in current context, but it was for now the most accurate answer in "all" cases.

Comment: And don't hesitate to redactor code inside the `BaseDoingThings`. You can also transform it using the composite pattern and avoid the list in the Test class. There is many variation to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write:

```
if (useSomething)
    //use something
if (useSomethingElse)
    //use somethingElse
if (useAnother)
    //use another
```

If you will add new booleans, I guess you'll do that by a `List`:

```
List<bool> useThings = new List<bool>();
// populate the list
foreach (var useThing in useThings)
{
    if (useThing)
        //useThatThing
}
```

Comment: Because that wouldn't do what OP wants.

Comment: are you sure? please recheck the code: "The first "quick" solution we had was:"

Comment: Not really - his quick solution is a tree of if-then-else statements nested three levels deep, covering the eight combinations of three boolean variables.

Comment: I think he's just trying to `use` the `thing` if `useThing` is true.

Comment: Interesting. This would definitely work for if you would want to change an Integer for example:
`int i = 0; if(one) i++; if(two)i -=1; if(three) i+5;`
But I would never be able to really "specifically" do something if one, two, three, one and two, etc. options are enabled. So it would mainly work with changing a value?

It so happens that in my current case I do change a value based on booleans, so thanks. I totally missed this haha. But for the actual concept this wouldn't be an option in "all" cases (if that's ever possible).

Comment: I just want to shake hands with the upvoter of the first comment under this answer.

Comment: @M.Bakker if you enable a boolean, related operation is called/done. I don't get the complexity you guys created from this case.

Comment: @IsThatSo Perhaps the complexity is a little odd in most scenario's, I've ran into this multiple times though and wanted to find a "best practice" of some kind to perform different actions when multiple booleans are involved.

Comment: i see. please don't forget to accept the most suitable answer for you and repay for their effort.

Comment: I need a level 15 reputation to upvote your answer ;) Thanks for your effort though! I didn't expect such quick responses.
In my current solution I will most likely use a combination of your answer and other solutions. But I chose the other answer as "solver" as I liked the OO in it and allows me to do different things in all 8 cases.

Comment: i just wanted to make sure mine/others' effort won't get wasted.