# JPA query to filter before, after and between optional start and end dates

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I'd like to write a JPA Repository query that can `findBy` with two optional query parameters, `startDate` and `endDate`:

| startDate | endDate | Return |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | null | All |
| null | endDate | Before End |
| startDate | null | After Start |
| startDate | endDate | Between Start and End |

How can this be implemented concisely? For example, using a single JPA `@Query` method with a SQL statement that can handle `null` or `Optional<Date>` parameters?

**EDIT**: I'm using PostgreSQL 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a naïve solution using 4 methods and a switch. It's clunky, but it works. This approach can get particularly verbose if more complex JPQL or SQL queries need to be implemented, since the 4 Repository methods and queries would need to be duplicated.

**Repository**

```java
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyObject> {
  List<MyObject> findByDateBetween(Date beforeDate, Date afterDate);
  List<MyObject> findByDateBefore(Date beforeDate);
  List<MyObject> findByDateAfter(Date afterDate);
  List<MyObject> findAll();
```

**Service**

```java
public List<MyObject> search(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
  int i = (startDate!=null ? 1 : 0) | (endDate!=null ? 2 : 0);
  switch(i) {
    case 0:
      return repository.findAll();
    case 1:
      return repository.findByDateAfter(startDate);
    case 2:
      return repository.findByDateBefore(endDate);
    case 3:
      return repository.findByDateBetween(startDate, endDate);
  }
}
```

(credit to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26347357/5752730) by Marc Gravell for the switch encoding)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query to achieve this. I took the freedom to use `<=` and `>=` but of course you can choose `<` and `>` instead or one of both. The idea was to give you a functioning query already.

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM MyObject m WHERE (:beforeDate is null or m.beforeDate >= :beforeDate) and (:afterDate is null or m.afterDate <= :afterDate)")
List<MyObject> findByDateBetween(Date beforeDate, Date afterDate);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I'm getting an error `PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1`. I suspect this is because I'm using Postgres. I updated my question to reflect that, since I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @DV82XL does it fix it if you use `LocalDate` instead ?

Comment: `LocalDate` didn't help. Replacing `:beforeDate is null` with `cast(:beforeDate as date) is null` works only when both `startDate` and `endDate` are provided (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64223435/5752730)). However, when any parameter is null, I get `ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to date`. This happens because JPQL still tries to evaluate the date comparison even when the parameter is null.

Comment: To determine parameter: 

```@Query("SELECT m FROM MyObject m WHERE (:beforeDate is null or m.beforeDate >= :beforeDate) and (:afterDate is null or m.afterDate <= :afterDate)")
List<MyObject> findByDateBetween(@Param("beforeDate") Date beforeDate,@Param("afterDate") Date afterDate);
```
Check my comment @DV82XL

Comment: @NguyễnVănQuyền The behavior is the same with or without `@Param`. JPA/Postgres fails because of the nulls.